# Dropdown navigation submenu renders behind other elements

Tags: html, css, angular

The submenus in my navigation bar are rendering behind the main content. More specifically, I have a navigation component which is right above another component containing an h1 element. The submenus in the navigation bar are visibly behind the h1 element in the main body component (because there is no background). It is also being hidden by the footer.

[image: problem]

In the main app component, the template looks like this:

```
<nova-header></nova-header>
<nova-navigation [categories]="categories"></nova-navigation>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<nova-footer [categories]="categories"></nova-footer>
```

What's strange is that I copy-pasted my code into JSFiddle, which you can see where I've separated the nova-navigation template HTML and the main body component HTML in the fiddle, however the problem is gone and the submenus render correctly. I'm new to Angular, so I assume I'm missing something with how Angular works.

Here's a link to said JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jonnylin13/nwxyd8j8/

I've tried z-index and overflow already

EDIT ** the problem must be with my local environment as I created a plnkr and the problem is not there. http://plnkr.co/edit/Pzzt6C4C9OrAvil50yqT?p=preview

Comment: Try to increase the z-index value in css for the menu

Comment: I've tried that already with pretty much all the divs out of desperation

Comment: We can't really debug this without a [mcve] unfortunately.

Comment: My solution is changeable z index..if i found my example i send u jquery sample

Comment: I'll try and recreate this in plnkr and edit the post

Answer (score 0):

As I can't comment, I will help you with answering. 
I can suggest you the z-index.
But you have to remember that z-index need the property position to work.

I hope this will help you, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Angular much, but I had similar issues with React: the framework adds elements into the DOM for handling the content (like wrapping animations and such). These elements interfere with the CSS positioning.

When you inspect the code in your browser, do you notice any extra `<span>` or `<div>` wrapping your elements?

If so, you may need to define extra CSS rules with a selector like `.content > span` to set their `position`, because [z-index only works on positioned elements](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).